# Как сделать переключатель шрифта для сайта с запоминанием выбора пользователя

Tags: javascript, html, шрифты

Делаю функцию переключения шрифта. Фактически, я уже сделал её. Осталось только понять, как запомнить выбор пользователя.

```html
<script>
function fontToPrata() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontFamily="Prata";
}

function fontToOpenSans() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontFamily="Open Sans";
}

function fontToComfortaa() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontFamily="Comfortaa";
}

function ReSize1() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontSize="80%";
}

function ReSize2() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontSize="110%";
}

function ReSize3() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontSize="130%";
}

</script>

 <div style="display:inline">
     <i>Шрифт: </i>
     <a href="#font-edit" style="font-family:'Prata';" title="По умолчанию" onclick="fontToPrata()">Prata</a> | <a href="#font-edit" style="font-family:'Open Sans';" onclick="fontToOpenSans()">OpenSans</a> | <a href="#font-edit" style="font-family:'Comfortaa';" onclick="fontToComfortaa()">Comfortaa</a>
     <br>
     <i>Размер: </i><a href="#font-edit" onclick="ReSize1()">S</a> | <a href="#font-edit" onclick="ReSize2()">N</a> | <a href="#font-edit" onclick="ReSize3()">B</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: sessionStorage или localStorage или Cookie.....

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сохранять данные вне зависимости от сессии, то используйте localStorage.

```
<script>
function fontToPrata() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontFamily="Prata";
    localStorage.setItem("fontFamily", "Prata");
}

function fontToOpenSans() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontFamily="Open Sans";
    localStorage.setItem("fontFamily", "Open Sans");
}

function fontToComfortaa() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontFamily="Comfortaa";
    localStorage.setItem("fontFamily", "Comfortaa");
}

function ReSize1() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontSize="80%";
    localStorage.setItem("fontSize", "80%");
}

function ReSize2() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontSize="110%";
    localStorage.setItem("fontSize", "110%");
}

function ReSize3() {
    var x=document.getElementById("article-post");
    x.style.fontSize="130%";
    localStorage.setItem("fontSize", "130%");
}

</script>

 <div style="display:inline">
     <i>Шрифт: </i>
     <a href="#font-edit" style="font-family:'Prata';" title="По умолчанию" onclick="fontToPrata()">Prata</a> | <a href="#font-edit" style="font-family:'Open Sans';" onclick="fontToOpenSans()">OpenSans</a> | <a href="#font-edit" style="font-family:'Comfortaa';" onclick="fontToComfortaa()">Comfortaa</a>
     <br>
     <i>Размер: </i><a href="#font-edit" onclick="ReSize1()">S</a> | <a href="#font-edit" onclick="ReSize2()">N</a> | <a href="#font-edit" onclick="ReSize3()">B</a>
 </div>
```

Если вы хотите применить сохранённые значения добавте к скрипту:

```
var x = document.getElementById("article-post");
x.style.fontFamily = localStorage.getItem("fontFamily");
x.style.fontSize = localStorage.getItem("fontSize");
```